# print N-Dimensional array in java

Tags: java, arrays

I want a generic method to print all the elements of a multidimensional array.
In the below code i am able to print all the elements of any multidimensional array which belongs to the parent Object class but not of any primitive types.
Is it possible to print all elements of a multidimensional array of primitive type.
One more doubt if int value can be hold in a Object type then why not int[] can be cast to Object[] but, String[] can be cast to Object[].

```
public class MultiDimension {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //final String ar[][][] = {{{"1","2"},{"3","4","5"}},{{"6","7","8"}},{{"9","10"},{"11"},{"12","13","14","15"}}};//new String[1][3][2][2];
        Integer intAr[][][][][][] = {{{{{{1},{2},{3}},{{4},{5},{6}}},{{{7}},{{8}}}}}};
        recPrintArray(intAr);
    }

    public static void recPrintArray(Object ar) {
        recPrintArray((Object[])ar,getDimensions(ar));
    }

    public static void recPrintArray(Object[] ar,int noODDimension) {
        for (Object obj:(Object[]) ar) {
            if (noODDimension > 0)
                recPrintArray((Object[])obj, noODDimension - 1);
            else {
                System.out.print("> " + obj + " ");
            }
        }
    }
    /*return the number of dimension of an array
     * takes any type as argument
     * using the Object class getClass() and Class class getName() methods 
     */
    public static int getDimensions(Object intAr) {
        return intAr.getClass().getName().lastIndexOf("[");
    }

}
```

Comment: for your Q2) int is primitive while String is not and since every class in java is child of Object class implicitly ie every class by default extends Object class directly(or indirectly like in multi level inheritance)

Comment: Correct but Object obj = (int)1; is also correct

Comment: `System.out.println(obj instanceof Integer); //prints true`

Comment: I got your point. I know Object is super class of every class by default. but we can also assign primitive to Object class also. How is that possible

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html

Comment: got it ? whats gonna happen eventually is this `Object obj2 = (int)1; // Integer.valueOf(1);`

Comment: Yes that part i got it  ...Thank you...one more doubt int[] is reference type and and Object can hold its reference right. How this happens

Comment: `int[]` cannot be implicitly casted to `Object[]` because `int` is not a sub-type of `Object`, but `int[][]` can because `int[]` can is a sub-type of `Object`. If you want to make your `recPrintArray` work with `int[]`, you need to use the `java.lang.reflect.Array` class.

Comment: i made it. thank you all for your valuable time.

Comment: since in java multidimensional arrays are array of array and array is an object. so if i recursively iterate on any array references in the last i will get only one dimensional array which i can type cast explicitly in the type supplied by using getClass().getName().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, we need to introduce the concept of [autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) first. Primitive types have their `class` matches. `int` has `Integer`, `double` has `Double` and so on. When a primitive type needs to be handled as an `Object`, the compiler will automatically convert the primitive into an instance of its wrapper `class`. Since you have an array of `Objects`, your primitive values are needed as `Objects`, so autoboxing will happen. If you want this to happen in a generic way, then you need to just check whether you have an array and if not, print the `Object` by calling its `toString` method.

As for your second question, you cannot convert a primitive array to an array of `Object`s, because your array was allocated for primitive types, not for `Object`s, but you can upcast a `String` array to an `Object` array, because all `String`s are `Object`s.

Comment: don't mention it :) it was a small one.

Answer (score 0):

since in java multidimensional arrays are array of array and array is an object. so if i recursively iterate on any array references in the last i will get only one dimensional array which i can type cast explicitly in the type supplied by using getClass().getName()

```
package learning;
public class MultiDimension {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String ar[][][] = {{{"1","2"},{"3","4","5"}},{{"6","7","8"}},{{"9","10"},{"11"},{"12","13","14","15"}}};//new String[1][3][2][2];
        //Integer integerAr[][] = {{1},{2}};
        //byte byteAr[][] = {{1},{2}};
        //int[] intAr = (int[])byteAr;
        recPrintArray(ar);
    }

    public static void recPrintArray(Object ar) {
        recPrintArray(ar,getDimensions(ar));
    }

    public static void recPrintArray(Object ar,int noOfDimension) {
        for (Object obj:(Object[]) ar) {
            if (noOfDimension > 1)
                recPrintArray(obj, noOfDimension - 1);
            else {
                String dataType = obj.getClass().getName();
                switch (dataType) {
                case "[B":
                    printAll((byte[]) obj);
                    break;
                case "[S":
                    printAll((short[]) obj);
                    break;
                case "[I":
                    printAll((int[]) obj);
                    break;
                case "[J":
                    printAll((long[]) obj);
                    break;
                case "[F":
                    printAll((float[]) obj);
                    break;
                case "[D":
                    printAll((double[]) obj);
                    break;
                case "[Z":
                    printAll((boolean[]) obj);
                    break;
                case "[C":
                    printAll((char[]) obj);
                default:
                    printAll((Object[]) obj);
                }
                //System.out.print("> " + obj + " ");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void printAll(byte[] ar) {
        for (byte val: ar)
            System.out.print(">" + val + " ");
    }

    public static void printAll(short[] ar) {
        for (short val: ar)
            System.out.print(">" + val + " ");
    }

    public static void printAll(int[] ar) {
        for (int val: ar)
            System.out.print(">" + val + " ");
    }

    public static void printAll(long[] ar) {
        for (long val: ar)
            System.out.print(">" + val + " ");
    }

    public static void printAll(float[] ar) {
        for (float val: ar)
            System.out.print(">" + val + " ");
    }

    public static void printAll(double[] ar) {
        for (double val: ar)
            System.out.print(">" + val + " ");
    }

    public static void printAll(char[] ar) {
        for (char val: ar)
            System.out.print(">" + val + " ");
    }

    public static void printAll(boolean[] ar) {
        for (boolean val: ar)
            System.out.print(">" + val + " ");
    }

    public static void printAll(Object[] ar) {
        for (Object val: ar)
            System.out.print(">" + val + " ");
    }
    /*return the number of dimension of an array
     * takes any reference type as argument
     * using the Object class getClass() and Class getName() methods 
     */
    public static int getDimensions(Object intAr) {
        return intAr.getClass().getName().lastIndexOf("[");
    }
}
```